# Smooth structures on $\mathbb{CP}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

How many distinct smooth structures does $\mathbb{CP}^3$ admit? How many almost-complex structures? How many complex structures? References would be great. Thanks.

Comment: According to https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12044-016-0269-4 it has a unique smooth structure.

Comment: @Cheerful Parsnip: On page 1 of the arxiv version (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.03032.pdf) of the above paper, the author states that "surgery theory tells us that there are infinitely many diffeomorphism types in the family of closed smooth manifolds homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{CP}^n$ for $n\geq 3$." The author doesn't provide a reference for this statement. Do you know where I can find an explanation of this?

Comment: If you are looking up to homotopy equivalence instead of homeomorphism then yes, there are infinitely many. I've crossed paths with surgery theory, but I'm not enough of an expert to tell you how it gives you infinitely many fake $\mathbb{CP}^n$s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only answers the second question but is much to long for a comment so...

By Proposition 8 of "CUBIC FORMS AND COMPLEX 3-FOLDS" by Okonek and Van de Ven, the almost complex structures are in bijection with integral lifts of the second Steifel Whitney class $w_{2} \in H^{2}(\mathbb{CP}^{3},\mathbb{Z}_{2})$. In this case $w_{2} = 0$, so almost complex structures on $\mathbb{CP}^{3}$ are in bijection with cohomolgy classes of the form $$2 \alpha \in H^{2}(\mathbb{CP}^{3},\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}.$$

In particular there are infinitely many distinct almost complex structures on $\mathbb{CP}^{3}$.

Such a cohomology class can be recovered from an almost complex structure by taking the first Chern class.